# Can you identify this vintage MTB?

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

[image: mysterybike]

I have quite a bit of experience with cycling in general mountain bikes especially. This bike got me stumped, it has a Titan racing stem, vintage Easton peregrine carbon str8 bars, Easton answer Manitou front shocks, headlock headset, deore LX groupset, and a seat post that has an "A" and a star and USA. The frame itself has a couple numbers under the bottom bracket but I haven't been able to come up with anything. Also on the under side of the down tube it has what appears to be an "easton" "E" stamped. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Nice bike - I'm picking a 90's vintage based on the quill stem.  Would you add a photo of the fork crown from the front?  That looks interesting.

Answer (score 6):

My Google-Fu comes up with the [1991 Alpinestar Ti Mega](http://www.pinkbike.com/news/now-that-was-a-bike-alpinestars-ti-mega-2014.html).  It looks like they made an aluminum version as well. The tube shapes look to be about the same.  Might be a good starting point for you.

Comment: Looks like a good match - Excellent finding skills!

Answer (score 5):

My friend had one, definitely Alpinestar. The forks are probably newer than '91, look like mid-90's Manitou's. The stock fork was probably rigid, someone swapped it out with the suspension fork.

Answer (score 0):

Alpinstars or Nishiki are the only two manufacturers that I know of that made a frame like that.

Comment: Do you have an example of a nishiki model that was styled in this way?

Comment: Everyone did elevated chainstays in early 1990s.

Comment: @ojs 'Everyone' is a stretch :). I know Haro also did it, but a lot of brands did not (GT, Specialized, Trek, Giant)

Answer (score -1):

Haro Extreme
Fat chance yo eddy

Comment: Welcome to SE - Do you have any supporting information?  Did/do you own one?   Images found via a google image search suggest that they did have raised chainstays, but looked more like this  https://i.pinimg.com/originals/fd/94/22/fd9422e378c39299ad00397803cf5e10.jpg     and another angle   http://www.retrobike.co.uk/forum/download/file.php?id=138696   so the double braces above the BB are quite different.   Good spotting though.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please consider expanding your answer to explain how you were able to identify the frame. A short, one-line answer like this is likely to get downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.

Comment: The google image search says that it's similar, but still different.